# What's the best way to load many lines of text in HTML (line by line every 60sec)?

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, html

I have a display page for my website.

I have the main centred text changing every 60seconds.

I have roughly 150+ individual lines of text, each of which I want the page to cycle through.

What's the best way to load these lines of text?

i.e.

1 by 1

Load them from another file?

Just would like the most efficient way to load the text.

```js
var divs = $('div[id^="content-"]').hide(),
  i = 0;

(function cycle() {

  divs.eq(i).fadeIn(2000)
    .delay(60000) // 1000 is 1 second
    .fadeOut(2000, cycle);

  i = ++i % divs.length;

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content-1">text 1</div>
<div id="content-2">text 2</div>
<div id="content-3">text 3</div>
<div id="content-4">text 4</div>
<div id="content-5">text 5</div>
<div id="content-6">text 6</div>
<div id="content-7">text 7</div>
......
<div id="content-180">text 180</div>
```

Comment: JSON and have a single div you write to, fade in, delay, fade out, write next value.. keeps the number of dom elements to 1

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a single text element that cycles its content on the 1 second interval Note that I am using a modulus operator to allow the cycle through the array (otherwise you sould be left with undefined awhen the count excceeded the array length.

Note that you can set this as a variable and then use clearInterval(variable); to stop the cycling.

I also do not have the fade animation- but hat should be easy to incorporate.

```js
var content = ['This is text content 1',' This is another text  content', 'I am also a text content']; 
let contentLength = content.length;
let count=0;

function contentDisplay (){
   document.querySelector('#content').innerText = content[count % contentLength];
  count++;
}

// sets the initial display
contentDisplay();

// sets the interval to change the display
setInterval(contentDisplay, 1000);
```

```css
#content {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 20px
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="content">text 1</p>
```

Comment: That's the first thing I thought about when I read the question!

Answer (score 0):

`async/await` is a nice pattern to use.

```js
var arr = ["foo","bar","test"];

function oneSecond() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve('resolved');
        }, 1010);
    });
}
async function writeToDom(arr) {
    console.log("beginning write");
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        await oneSecond();
        console.log(arr[i]);
    }
    console.log("done.");
}
writeToDom(arr);
```

Comment: Looks like serious overkill to me to wrap a setTimeout in a promise....

Answer (score 0):

150 lines of text is very little for modern browsers, even on small mobile phones. You can simply have the text in javascript and set the content of a single div over and over again. That is much more efficient than creating many divs.

```js
var lines = [
    "Text line 1",
    "Text line 2",
    "etc"
];

var div = $('div[id="content"]');
var i = 0;

(function cycle() {

  div
    .text(lines[i])
    .fadeIn(2000)
    .delay(60000) // 1000 is 1 second
    .fadeOut(2000, cycle);

  i = ++i % lines.length;

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: Your snippet does not run

Comment: I wasn't aware that it was possible to have a working example here. Thanks for fixing the snippet!

Comment: It is not mandatory, but it shows the example works. Your example does not actually work at the moment

Comment: It does here :-) You have to wait 60 seconds before the text changes.

Comment: Ahh - that is not  a useful example - lower it to 3 secs or so